# Python: finding and replacing a symbol in a file on if followed by specific word

Tags: python, replace

I'm new to Python and didn't do any coding for years...
I need to elaborate a dictionary: to replace a " "(space charachter) between "word" and "definition" with " "(tab charachter). As a "word" could be not only a single word but a couple of them forming a phrase as well, I thought of replacing a " " if followed by "adj." for example. This is what I came up with..any ideas? thanks

```
>file1 = open('v.txt','r')

>file2 = open('v.txt','w')
>
>>  for line in file1:
>>>    for x in line
>>>>      if x = ' ':
>>>>      and x+1='adj':
>>>>      or x+1='verb':
>>>>      or x+1='-':
>>>>      x='   '
>
>
>file1.close()
>  
>file2.close()
```

Forgot to mention that data is in Cyrillic, eg:
*тәрбиясезлек сущ невоспитанность

тәрбияче сущ 1. воспитатель 2. кормилец

тәрбиячесез пр беспризорный

тәре сущ 1. в разн зн крест 2. икона 3. крестовик 4. треф (масть игральной карты)*

Comment: Please post couple of rows from that dictionary so it will be easier to understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Matching a character only if followed by a set of other words is best done using a regular expression:

```
import re
for line in file1:
    line = re.sub(r" (?=adj|verb|-)", "\t", line)
    file2.write(line)
```

Comment: Your third line lacks a closing paren. Here, I have a spare: `)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the insight by @Tim and other answers on this website I managed it this way (dealing with Cyrrilic):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
file1 = codecs.open('d.txt', 'r', "utf-8")
file2 = codecs.open('d1.txt', 'w', "utf-8")

import re
re.UNICODE
for line in file1:
    line = re.sub(ur" (?=сущ |гл |подр |пр |нар |межд |союз |предлог |предик |мест |част |I|II|III|вводн |посл |числ |в знач |в вводн предл |мод с |см |: |1. |[(]|-)", "\t", line, count=1, flags=re.U)
    file2.write(line)


file1.close()
file2.close()
```